# Javascript completely skipping over function in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm trying to make a nav bar menu with a drop down menu and use JS/jQuery to make the drop down menu fade in and out. I have it set to where the menu fades in when hovering over the "photography" button but when you move the mouse off the "photography" button the dropdown just disappears instead of fading out. I've inserted some alerts to test which part of the code it's missing and it completely skips the fadeOut() function. I created a fiddle with all my code. The formatting isn't perfect on the fiddle but enough to get the point across.

HTML:

```
<ul class="navBarContainer">
  <li class="btn"><a class="btnText" href="AboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li class="btn" id="btnHover">
    <a class="btnText" href="Photography.html">Photography</a>
    <ul class="dropDown" id="photography">
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-Nature.html">Nature</a></li>
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-People.html">People</a></li>
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-Skiing.html">Skiing</a></li>
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-Trampoline.html">Trampoline</a></li>
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-Urban.html">Urban</a></li>
      <li class="dropBtn"><a class="dropBtnText" href="Photography-Vehicles.html">Vehicles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="btn"><a class="btnText" href="Cinematography.html">Cinematography</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a class="btnText" href="ContactMe.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/*container for the nav bar*/

.navBarContainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75vw;
}

.navBarContainer .btn {
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: background-color .75s;
  -o-transition: background-color .75s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .75s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .75s;
    list-decoration: none;
}

.navBarContainer .btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.btn .btnText {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .75s;
  -o-transition: color .75s;
  -moz-transition: color .75s;
  -webkit-transition: color .75s;
}

.btn:hover .btnText {
  color: black;
}

.dropDown {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 25vw;
  max-width: 25%;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dropBtn {
  background: black;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.dropBtn:hover {
  background: white;
}

.dropBtn:hover > .dropBtnText {
  color: black;
}

.dropBtnText {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnHover').hover(function () {
        document.getElementById('photography').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = 0;

        var opacity = 0;
        function fadeIn() {
            if (opacity < 1) {
                opacity += .1;
                setTimeout(function () { fadeIn() }, 75);
            }
            document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = opacity.toString();
        }
        document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = 1;
    },
        function () {
            document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = 1;
            function fadeOut() {
                alert("test2");
                if (opacity > 0) {
                    opacity -= .1;
                    setTimeout(function () { fadeOut() }, 75);
                }
                document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = opacity.toString();
            }

            document.getElementById('photography').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('photography').style.opacity = 0;
        });
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1hkL589/10/

Comment: You are defining those functions (`fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`) but never actually calling them. The fading you see is due to `transition`

Comment: You're never calling your fadeIn or fadeOut functions outside of the functions themselves. You actually have to run the functions somewhere with `fadeOut()` although for something like this your code seems overly complex. Could probably just be using CSS or the jquery fadeIn/fadeOut functions

Comment: Wow figured it was something dumb like that thanks